# How to distribute static files by url in next 13?

Tags: next.js, next.js13

In Express it was so easy with .static

```
const path = require('path')
app.use('/static', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')))
```

I wanted to get all files from public folder by url where last part is name of file as `http://localhost:3000/my_file_from_public_folder.png`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Next.js has this built in. Create a `public` folder in the root of your project (if not already created) and then a file in it that you want to access through the url directly. For example, if I have a **data.json** file in `public`, I can access it from `/data.json`.

Here are the url examples tied to the files

```
public/data.json        -> /data.json
public/folder/hello.txt -> /folder/hello.txt
```

The Next.js Docs for the `public` directory: https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/optimizing/static-assets

Comment: I've tried this before, but it didn't work, but it's fine now. Very strange, apparently I missed something earlier. Thanks

Comment: Can you share what the missing thing was?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what is it was. But u can check repo here https://github.com/EliotCampbell/next-js-store . I used images in products previews