My video doesn't come up even though the src is correct in Nextjs13
I'm trying to add a video component to my web app but it never comes up, i make sure i get the src correctly, i even added the video in my app folder and it still doesn't work heres the code:
<video controls preload="none"> <source src="nature-vid-1.mp4" type="video/mp4" /> </video> 
I tried adding the video to my app folder, using next-video(I got a huge watermark when i tried this), aI even tried embedding the video using Iframes

dont put video in app folder instead use static folders - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76886201/how-to-distribute-static-files-by-url-in-next-13 and https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/optimizing/static-assets

Try and make sure the video file path is correct relative to your HTML file, and check for any console errors or issues.
